# Understanding the effective low-energy Lagrangian for hadrons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, effective-field-theory

My course in Higgs Physics is discussing a two-nucleon low-energy effective theory of hadron interaction. With $\psi=(p,n)$, the pion is defined as

$\vec{\pi}= i \bar{\psi}\vec{\tau} \gamma_5 \bar{\psi} $

and the sigma as

$\sigma = \bar{\psi}\psi$

Then the Lagrangian is:

$L=$

$\bar{\psi} i \partial_\mu \psi + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \vec{\pi} \partial^\mu \vec{\pi} + \partial_\mu \sigma \partial^\mu \sigma$) (kinetic)

$+ g_\pi  (i \bar{\psi} \gamma_5 \vec{\tau}  \bar{\psi} ) \vec{\pi} + g_\pi \bar{\psi}\psi\sigma$ (nucleon-pion-interaction)

$+ \frac{\lambda}{4}((\pi^2+\sigma^2)^2-f_\pi^2)^2$ (potential)

First, I am surprised that the nucleon current in the nucleon-pion-interaction $ (i \bar{\psi} \gamma_5 \vec{\tau}  \bar{\psi} )$ is almost the same as the definition of the pion $(i \bar{\psi}\vec{\tau} \gamma_5 \bar{\psi})$. In fact they seem to be equal since $[\tau_i,\gamma_5]=0$. ( $\tau_i$ acts on the SU(2)-space while $\gamma_5$ acts on the left-right space.)

*Why are we reading the same term once as a pion and once as a nucleon current?*

Secondly, $f_\pi$ is referred to as the pion decay constant. It is supposed to be proportional to the coupling of a pion to the W-Boson.

*Why is $\pi$ included into the potential in the way it is? How do I see that it is related to the W-Boson coupling?*

Comment: Shouldn't the second term in line 2 of the Lagrangian be $g_\pi \bar{\psi} \psi \sigma$? Are there terms quadratic in $\vec{\pi}$ and $\sigma$ missing? The first two equations that relate fermion bilinears to $\vec{\pi}$ and $\sigma$ should arise their ($\pi$ and $\sigma$) equations of motion.

Comment: You were right, I corrected it now.

Comment: I am sorry, I got it messed up a bit. The way I understand it, $\psi$ can be understood either as (u,d) or as (p,n). I will make my question less confusing by replacing the quarks with nucleons everywhere.

Comment: (This was a response to adams comment which I do not see any more right now.)

Comment: I think you are mixing two things: the interaction between pion and nucleons in the lagrangian (where $\psi=(p,n)$), and the definition of pions in terms of quarks (with $\psi=(u,d)$).

Comment: Yeah, I wrote about that, but then I was not sure anymore, so I deleted it. But see my new comment...

Comment: You should just forget about this lagrangian (vestiges from the 60') and look instead at the modern, accurate, well understood and checked chiral lagrangian as the effective theory of pions. It's a theory where pions are pseudo-goldstone bosons emerging from the (approximate) spontaneous symmetry $SU(2)_L\times SU(2)_R$ broken down to the the diagonal isospin, $SU(2)_{L+R}$. The model you have written may catch some of the physical information since the fields have the right quantum numbers, i.e. they transform in the correct way under the unbroken $SU(2)_{L+R}$.

Comment: @Adam , so what you are basically saying is that once I read $\psi$ as (u,d), the contraction is a pion. And once I read it as (p,n), it is a nucleon current. This makes some sense in fact, but then why didn't my teacher use different symbols? *angry*

Comment: It would be better to have a confirmation by someone else (I'm not an expert on that subject), but it seems likely. And agreed, bad notations are bad, but almost everywhere, unfortunately...